# kubectl (google container engine): can't retrieve rollout history of deployments

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I cannot retrieve the rollout history of my deployments. I get an error:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployments
deployments "letsencrypt-live-deployment":
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
2       <none>
3       <none>

deployments "openvpn-live-deployment":
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
1       <none>
3       <none>
4       <none>
5       <none>
6       <none>
7       <none>
8       <none>

deployments "ployst-api-db-live-deployment":
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
2       <none>
3       <none>

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xb8 pc=0xa1bc1a]
```

Looks like a bug somewhere in GKE.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.2", GitCommit:"528f879e7d3790ea4287687ef0ab3f2a01cc2718", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.2", GitCommit:"528f879e7d3790ea4287687ef0ab3f2a01cc2718", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a temporary issue in the GKE service.